# vector<shared_ptr<>> Clear Error

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

I have the following problems:

When I try to clear **v_doc** and keep the last element I get the following error:

> C:\Users\hdaher\Documents\Project\CR_Verification\main.cpp|292|error:
>   no matching function for call to
>   'std::vector
>
> > ::clear(std::vector >::iterator, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator*, std::vector > >)'|

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     //Declare a vector of type Document
     vector<shared_ptr<Document>> v_doc;

      //Works ok
      v_doc.clear();

      //Error HERE!! Clearn V_doc and keep only the last element
      v_doc.clear(v_doc.begin(),v_doc.end()-1);
      return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.erase`, also check if the entry iterators are valid or not:

```
if (v_doc.size() > 1)
    v_doc.erase(v_doc.begin(),v_doc.end()-1);
```

Answer (score 4):

[clear](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) has no overloads. Only `clear` without arguments is available. It looks like you want to call [erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase).